# Best jQuery Mobile Prototyping Tool?

Tags: jquery-mobile

What is the best tool to prototype a jquery mobile based app ? I would prefer one that runs on desktop as opposed to cloud based.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.electricplum.com/ to get mine off the ground. jsFiddle.net also allows you to do work on their fiddler and connect it to mobile (however this is a cloud solution).

Answer (score 0):

http://Xiffe.com is the most comprehensive mobile prototyping tool, providing prototyping for all major mobile platforms

It has a drag and drop interface and support for app workflow simulation by linking screens through button clicks. Supports iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

Comment: Their page doesn't talk about any language, like jQuery. Can you confirm jQuery is included?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Codiqa's web-based product and it is good.  They just released a desktop based version with a free 7 day trial: https://codiqa.com/desktop